# Convert from OrderedDict to list

Tags: python

How to convert from OrderedDict

```
OrderedDict([(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')])
```

to a list?

```
[(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')]
```

THX!!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

On Python 2.x, simply use the [`items`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dct = OrderedDict([(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')])
>>> dct.items()
[(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')]
>>>
```

On Python 3.x, do the same but also put it in [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/functions.html#list):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dct = OrderedDict([(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')])
>>> list(dct.items())
[(73, 'Mocha My Day'), (77, 'Coffee Cafe'), (83, 'Flavour Fusion'), (85, 'Mexican Grill')]
>>>
```