# pickle data was truncated pytorch

Tags: python, sockets, pytorch, pickle

I am trying to send model.state_dict() from server to client using socket programming. While doing this, I am constantly getting error saying "pickle data was truncated" from the client-side. Now, this is not the case if I send anything other than PyTorch model. I have included a for loop to accumulate data and also used sendall command as suggested in this question [python 3.6 socket pickle data was truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44637809/python-3-6-socket-pickle-data-was-truncated)
I even tried to convert my state_dict to a list using this question [Convert from OrderedDict to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431270/convert-from-ordereddict-to-list) : But still same error.

Attaching my server and client code below:

Server

```
def recv(connection, buffer_size=4096):
    received_data = b""
    while str(received_data)[-2] != '.':
        received_data += connection.recv(buffer_size)
    received_data = pickle.loads(received_data)
    return received_data

num_comm = 5
device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
class VideoRecog_Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(VideoRecog_Model, self).__init__()
        self.base_model = nn.Sequential(*list(r3d_18(pretrained=True).children())[:-1])
        self.fc = nn.Linear(512, 51)
    def forward(self, x):
        out = self.base_model(x).squeeze(4).squeeze(3).squeeze(2)
        out = torch.log_softmax(self.fc(out), dim=1)
        return out

def set_parameter_requires_grad_video(model):
    for param in model.parameters():
        param.requires_grad = False
    model.fc.weight.requires_grad = True
    model.fc.bias.requires_grad = True

global_network = VideoRecog_Model().to(device)
set_parameter_requires_grad_video(global_network)
print("Model Done")

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
serversocket.bind((host, port))  
serversocket.listen(5)            

for epoch in range(num_comm):
    print("process started")
    connection, client_info = serversocket.accept()
    send_dict = {"data":global_network.state_dict()}
    connection.sendall(pickle.dumps(send_dict))
    received_data = recv(connection=connection, buffer_size=4096)

serversocket.close()
```

Client Code

```
def recv(soc, buffer_size=4096):
    received_data = b""
    while str(received_data)[-2] != '.':
        received_data += soc.recv(buffer_size)
    received_data = pickle.loads(received_data)
    return received_data

while(True):
    soc = socket.socket()
    soc.connect((host, TCP_PORT))
    print("connected")
    received_data = recv(soc=soc, buffer_size=4096)
    print("Received")
    soc.sendall(pickle.dumps(received_data))
    print("Data sent")
    soc.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>     while str(received_data)[-2] != '.':
> ```

Why do you think that the pickled representation contains no period other than the second to last byte? If in any transmission chunk the penultimate byte is a period, the receiving is broken. I'd drop the whole `recv` function and just use

```
received_data = pickle.load(soc.makefile('b'))
```